# Empathy won't connect to my Facebook account

Tags: 13.10, empathy, facebook

When I try to connect Empathy to my Facebook account, the following error appears:

[image: Screenshot]

Rough translation: "Error connecting to the app. Sorry, but the app you are trying to access doesn't exist or was deactivated."

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem. I suspect it's not supported anymore :(